# How can I change the format of the dates produced when using ALTER COLUMN to convert a datetime column to varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, varchar, alter

I have a datetime column that I need to alter to be a varchar column.

Using the statement below, the strings produced have this format: "Jan 18 2010  5:28PM"

```
ALTER TABLE Thinger
ALTER COLUMN LastUpdateDate varchar(16) NOT NULL
```

I would like strings produced to have a yyyyMMdd format (giving 20100118) instead. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to change the table this way? Are they not really dates?

Comment: how are you populating this table - using Stored Procedure? Then get the value as a datetime and do the conversion inside the procedure.

Comment: The dates are being imported from a set of files. The files list the dates this way so they can store just the year and month and leave day undefined by setting those digits to zero (20110800).  I suppose this means they are not _always_ dates, which is causing problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bad, Bad idea**...never ever store dates in varchar columns, now you will get garbage in there in different formats
Also why varchar(16) when you want yyyyMMdd?

if you want the output to be in a different format do it in the presentation layer or use convert

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112)
```

now if you really want to do what you say you want to do

run your script and then do

```
UPDATE Table 
SET LastUpdateDate  =  CONVERT(CHAR(8),(CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(varchar,LastUpdateDate))),112)
```

But again..**bad bad bad** idea

Also the next version of SQL Server will make formatting a lot easier see: [Format function in SQL Server Denali CTP3](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/format-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: I agree that it's a bad idea, but the dates in the files I'm working with are coming to me that way. Originally, I chose to store the dates as datetimes, but the date strings that we receive are too often invalid dates. They'll have dates like Feb 30th and other nonsense like that. Or they will have missing (or extra) characters in them. That's why I was using varchar(16)-- even if the crap dates are wrong, I'll still need to store what I've got until they're corrected.  Also, the dates sometimes are written 19750400 indicating that only the year and month are known, and datetime can't do that

Comment: Then you need to go beat whoever is giving you invalid dates.  Preferrably with a large, heavy object.  In the meantime, I'd have a 'translation' or 'staging' table/column where you store the invalid dates until they can be worked - don't actually store the invalid dates in your main table/key.  And figure out a business rule for dates that are missing times - use midnight or some other sensible time.  Don't just use the invalid dates, or it'll gain inertia...

Comment: I see what you mean, but the requirements are that the reports show exactly what is provided (even if the date is wrong). And the people who are giving me invalid dates are the U.S. Government. XD

Answer (score 2):

Try this script:

```
ALTER TABLE Thinger ADD LastUpdateDateText VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
GO

UPDATE Thinger SET LastUpdateDateText = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), LastUpdateDate, 112)
GO

ALTER TABLE Thinger DROP COLUMN LastUpdateDate
GO

sp_RENAME 'Thinger.LastUpdateDateText' , 'LastUpdateDate', 'COLUMN'
GO
```